# async NamedPipeClientStream implementation feedback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, pipe, named

Presently, I have implemented named pipes using demo code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx.  Instead of the synchronous client; however, I want to make it asynchronous.  Here is my implementation, where the main program makes a call to StartClientNamedPipeListening():

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Buffer where received bytes or bytes received are stored 
    /// </summary>
    private byte[] _byteBuffer = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback result for reading data from the named pipe
    /// </summary>
    private IAsyncResult _pipeResult;

    /// <summary>
    /// Named object to send and receive data to and from watchdog
    /// </summary>
    NamedPipeClientStream _pipeClient;

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies waiting threads that an event has occurred
    /// </summary>
    protected ManualResetEvent _pipeReadDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private object _pipeState = new object();

    private void StartClientNamedPipeListening()
    {
            // open and then close the gate as soon as after one thread passed,
            // i.e., put the event into a non-signaled, or closed, state:
            _pipeReadDone.Reset();

            // Reads the data coming in from the pipe and call the 
            // thread safe delegate to get the data received.
            _byteBuffer = new Byte[50];
            _pipeResult = _pipeClient.BeginRead(_byteBuffer, 0,
                _byteBuffer.Length, PipeReadCallback, _pipeState);

            // worker thread block in here (waiting for...
            // _pipeReadDone.Set()), i.e., wait for the door to be opened
            _pipeReadDone.WaitOne();            
    }

   private void PipeReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;

        // if port serial is open and..
        if (_pipeClient.IsConnected)
        {
            // the stream can read then..
            if (_pipeClient.CanRead)
            {
                // wait for asynchronous read to be completed
                bytesRead = _pipeClient.EndRead(ar);
            }
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            StreamString ss = new StreamString(_pipeClient);
            // Validate the server's signature string 
            if (ss.ReadString() == "I am the one true server!")
            {
                // The client security token is sent with the first write. 
                // Send the name of the file whose contents are returned 
                // by the server.
                ss.WriteString(@"C:\Temp\namedpipestring.txt");

                // Print the file to the screen.
                Console.WriteLine(ss.ReadString(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server could not be verified.");
            }

            // put the event into a signaled, or open,  state: 
            // open gate for next data
            _pipeReadDone.Set();

            // Start waiting for the next watchdog message
            StartClientNamedPipeListening();
        }
    }
```

This implementation works according to my tests; however, I was wondering, am I doing some obvious no-no's?  Does anyone have any suggestions on how it could possibly be implemented better?  TIA.

Comment: this appears to be well suited for code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think I have the privilege to be able to move it.  Do you know how to move this post to that forum?

Comment: Sure, there's an obvious flaw.  It *completely* makes no sense to use BeginRead() and then block until the response is received.  Just call Read().  If you meant it to be async then this is not close, it means "don't wait".

Comment: So I should just get rid of the _pipeReadDone data member entirely?

Comment: How would I need to change it to make it async?

Comment: Is my answer below correct for implementing the client asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I modified the code to get it to work asynchronously.  I'm not sure why I thought I needed the ManualResetEvent:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Buffer where received bytes or bytes received are stored 
    /// </summary>
    private byte[] _byteBuffer = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback result for reading data from the named pipe
    /// </summary>
    private IAsyncResult _pipeResult;

    /// <summary>
    /// Named object to send and receive data to and from watchdog
    /// </summary>
    NamedPipeClientStream _pipeClient;

    private object _pipeState = new object();

    private void StartClientNamedPipeListening()
    {
            _pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe",
                PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);
            _pipeClient.Connect();
            // Reads the data coming in from the pipe and call the 
            // thread safe delegate to get the data received.
            _byteBuffer = new Byte[50];
            _pipeResult = _pipeClient.BeginRead(_byteBuffer, 0,
                _byteBuffer.Length, PipeReadCallback, _pipeState);      
    }

   private void PipeReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;

        // if port serial is open and..
        if (_pipeClient.IsConnected)
        {
            // the stream can read then..
            if (_pipeClient.CanRead)
            {
                // wait for asynchronous read to be completed
                bytesRead = _pipeClient.EndRead(ar);
            }
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            StreamString ss = new StreamString(_pipeClient);
            // Validate the server's signature string 
            if (ss.ReadString() == "I am the one true server!")
            {
                // The client security token is sent with the first write. 
                // Send the name of the file whose contents are returned 
                // by the server.
                ss.WriteString(@"C:\Temp\namedpipestring.txt");

                // Print the file to the screen.
                Console.WriteLine(ss.ReadString(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server could not be verified.");
            }

            // Start waiting for the next watchdog message
            StartClientNamedPipeListening();
        }
    }
```

Thanks, Hans.

Comment: Why not use TPL and `Task.Factory.FromAsync`?

Comment: I am not familiar with Task.Factory, but thanks for the suggestion.  I'll have to look into it.

Comment: In fact, a preferred way would be to just use `NamedPipeClientStream.ReadAsync` and `NamedPipeClientStream.WriteAsync` with `async`/`await`.

Comment: Because it's [already implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs#63db0f8d08c54a3e) for you using `BeginRead/EndRead`. If you use it with `async/await`, your code will be smaller (as it's gonna be pseudo-linear without callbacks), more readable and less error-prone.